# how to make django server and angular client side projects different with CSRF protection

Tags: python, django, angularjs, django-csrf, csrf-protection

I have read different blogs about django and angular, but all of them have client side (HTML+CSS+JS) codes inside django project.

All I want to do is create two projects: One with all client side stack ( HTML+JS+CSS) and another with Django and Django-rest-framework only. This means that I could write all my presentation code in different project and server code in different project but link them together using REST api.

But there comes a threat which I should always consider CSRF against which Django's CSRF Middleware provide nice security.
So, is it possible to put my client codes outside the Django project directory but still get protected against CSRF?

Answer (score 4):

Read the documentation, everything is explained well. The cleanest way to do this is when you will submit your data using Ajax, you have to add a custom header X-CSRFToken. The token can be parsed from the cookies, which should be enabled by the way. Here is a link to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).

The documentation is always the best place to find your questions, you just have to read mate. But anyway, here is an example:

```
// Using the jquery cookie plugin, you can get the csrf token like this 
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
```

Then in your javascript/Anuglar code, to post or make ajax request, you have to add the `X-CSRFToken` header before making the POST/PUT request:

```
// This HTTP method doesn't need protection since you will be reading and not pushing data
//   into the server
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

// This is for setting up the upcoming ajax request, here you add the header with the
//   csrftoken you got it from the cookies
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

**NB:** This is using jQuery, you can still do the same thing using Angular.

After this you can make your Ajax call and Django will happily accept your request, again RTD please, everything is well explained, you have all of this code examples included.

Comment: As in documentation we must first get CSRF token. In django, we put {% csrf_token %} inside a template file. But I want my angularjs completely separated i.e. not to be rendered by django web framework by which this token will not be replaced. So without putting {% csrf_token %} code is it possible to protect by csrf middleware

Comment: You don't have to do that since the csrf_token is passed through cookies,  and you can access that through the javascript/Angular.js code

Comment: There you, but please read the doc you will find more information there, cheers.